# How to config Squid SSL bump to let Paloalto PA series firewall recognize App-ID

Tags: squid, linux-networking, security, palo-alto-networks

A Paloalto firewall(PA-2050,POS 4.1x) was capable of recognizing the websites which users are visiting(thru http/https) then flag them with a App-ID and apply application control on the traffic, for instance blocking all webmail/file sharing/social media... etc.

But PA-2050 can only recognize those traffic visiting websites with https as "SSL" after we setup a Squid proxy 3.4 with SSL bump before the firewall. This crippling the application control mechanism of PA firewall.

Anyone knows how to config Squid 3.4 (or PA-2050) so as to recover the application control capability on https traffic thru Squid proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The Palo Alto firewall can be set to use a Decryption policy to inspect the traffic after it passes through the Squid proxy.  This will then allow the Palo Alto to see the decrypted traffic and once again assign *meaningful* App-IDs.  See [How to Implement SSL Decryption](https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/docs/DOC-1412).